# Import text files into OneNote as pages?

Tags: conversion, microsoft-onenote, notepad

I recently got OneNote 2007.  Previously I kept all my notes in standalone Notepad documents (.txt).  I have roughly 250 of these text files.

Is there any quick way to get them all into OneNote as pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Guin at Microsoft (MSDN) wrote an import tool that should be able to handle this.

His bug fix post with some screenshots:
"**Updating the OneNote Text File Importer**"
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnguin/archive/2009/02/23/updating-the-onenote-text-file-importer.aspx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/johnguin/updating-the-onenote-text-file-importer)

And the link to the original post that has the updated code you can install:
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnguin/archive/2007/04/30/customer-feedback-results-in-another-powertoy.aspx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/johnguin/customer-feedback-results-in-another-powertoy)

Comment: Oddly enough, the setup program didn't work, but I ran the code in VS2010, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else was still trying to do this using OneNote 2016, I realised that Evernote allows you to set an import folder and will import text files as notes with the title as the first line. You can then use the Evernote to Onenote import tool. The linked tool above no longer works with new versions, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a way to do this with OneNote 2016 and have a OneDrive account available, you can use the ["Create a OneNote Page for every new file created in OneDrive" Flow](https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/e28e68e0193e11e7b6a6f17fc321b124/) to automate this process:

[image: Create a OneNote Page for every new file created in OneDrive for Business]

Do note that this Flow template doesn't try to batch operations or respect the throttling limit, so you'll end up with a bunch of failed runs :(

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill - any recommendations on how to do this for a link to a specific Microsoft flow? I'll add a screenshot of the page.